# When I put my program into different methods, and combine them in a loop, they don't read each other properly. Anyone know why?

Tags: c#, loops, methods

I'm making a tic tac toe game and heres part of my code.
When I put my all my methods together in a loop, my switch statement isn't reading the user's input (for example if I want to place a piece on 6), but reads it as "playerOneMove" which creates an invalid option. Can anyone see my mistake? Idk how to keep playerOneMove as the users input when I go to the next method inside the loop. Thanks.

```
while(gameDone == false)
{
    DrawBoard ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    GetSpaceOne("playerOne");
    PlacePieceOne ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "playerOne");
    DrawBoard ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    GetSpaceTwo("playerTwo");
    PlacePieceTwo ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "playerTwo");
}

private static void DrawBoard (string spaceOne, string spaceTwo, string spaceThree, string spaceFour, string spaceFive, string spaceSix, string spaceSeven, string spaceEight, string spaceNine)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.WriteLine("| " + spaceOne + " | " + spaceTwo + " | " + spaceThree + " |");
    Console.WriteLine("|---|---|---|");
    Console.WriteLine("| " + spaceFour + " | " + spaceFive + " | " + spaceSix + " |");
    Console.WriteLine("|---|---|---|");
    Console.WriteLine("| " + spaceSeven + " | " + spaceEight + " | " + spaceNine + " |");
    Console.ResetColor();
}

private static string GetSpaceOne (string playerOne)
{
    string playerOne;
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("Player One (1-9): ");
    playerOne = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
}

private static void PlacePieceOne (string spaceOne, string spaceTwo, string spaceThree, string spaceFour, string spaceFive, string spaceSix, string spaceSeven, string spaceEight, string spaceNine, string playerOneMove)
{
    Console.WriteLine(playerOneMove);
    switch (playerOneMove)
    {
        case "1":
            spaceOne = spaceOne.Replace("1", "X");
            break;
        case "2":
            spaceTwo = spaceTwo.Replace("2", "X");
            break;
        case "3":
            spaceThree = spaceThree.Replace("3", "X");
            break;
        case "4":
            spaceFour = spaceFour.Replace("4", "X");
            break;
        case "5":
            spaceFive = spaceFive.Replace("5", "X");
            break;
        case "6":
            spaceSix = spaceSix.Replace("6", "X");
            break;
        case "7":
            spaceSeven = spaceSeven.Replace("7", "X");
            break;
        case "8":
            spaceEight = spaceEight.Replace("8", "X");
            break;
        case "9":
            spaceNine = spaceNine.Replace("9", "X");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option. Please try again");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't return anything from `GetSpaceOne` and you don't do anything with the result either when you call the method. You should get a warning that says `C4715... Not all control paths return a value.` for `GetSpaceOne`.

Comment: Try to rewrite this using jagged/multidimensional arrays, it will remove ~90% of your code.

Comment: added an answer and explanation on what is wrong with the way you are accessing variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a lot of problem here

```
private static void PlacePieceOne (string spaceOne, string spaceTwo, string spaceThree, string spaceFour, string spaceFive, string spaceSix, string spaceSeven, string spaceEight, string spaceNine, string playerOneMove)
```

your `playerOneMove` in your function parameter is not the same as your

```
string playerOneMove;
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.Write("Player One (1-9): ");
playerOneMove = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
```

the `playerOneMove` inside the `GetSpaceOne` is not accessible in your `PlacePieceOne`

so the value of the `playerOneMove` in the function `PlacePieceOne` is
`playerOne` as stated in here

```
PlacePieceOne ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "playerOne");
```

also you are trying to access `spaceOne`, `spaceTwo`,...`spaceNine` which is inside a function/scoppe and you are accessing it in a different scope

for better solution for a tictac using your functions

```
private static string spaceOne = "1";
private static string spaceTwo = "2";
.... till spaceNine;

while(gameDone == false)
{
    DrawBoard();
    GetPlayerOneMove();
    DrawBoard();
    GetPlayerTwoMove();
}

private static void DrawBoard()
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Console.WriteLine("| " + spaceOne + " | " + spaceTwo + " | " + spaceThree + " |");
    Console.WriteLine("|---|---|---|");
    Console.WriteLine("| " + spaceFour + " | " + spaceFive + " | " + spaceSix + " |");
    Console.WriteLine("|---|---|---|");
    Console.WriteLine("| " + spaceSeven + " | " + spaceEight + " | " + spaceNine + " |");
    Console.ResetColor();
}

private static void GetPlayerOneMove()
{
    bool playerMoveValid = false;
    while(!playerMoveValid)
    {
        string playerOne;
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.Write("Player One (1-9): ");
        playerOne = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());

        switch (playerOne)
        {
            case "1":
                if(spaceOne == "1")
                {
                    spaceOne = spaceOne.Replace("1", "X");
                    break;
                    playerMoveValid = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    playerMoveValid = false;
                }
            case "2":
                spaceTwo = spaceTwo.Replace("2", "X");
                break;
            case "3":
                spaceThree = spaceThree.Replace("3", "X");
                break;
            case "4":
                spaceFour = spaceFour.Replace("4", "X");
                break;
            case "5":
                spaceFive = spaceFive.Replace("5", "X");
                break;
            case "6":
                spaceSix = spaceSix.Replace("6", "X");
                break;
            case "7":
                spaceSeven = spaceSeven.Replace("7", "X");
                break;
            case "8":
                spaceEight = spaceEight.Replace("8", "X");
                break;
            case "9":
                spaceNine = spaceNine.Replace("9", "X");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option. Please try again");
                break;
        }
    }
}

private static void GetPlayerTwoMove()
{
    string playerTwo;
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("Player Two(1-9): ");
    playerTwo= Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (playerTwo)
    {
        case "1":
            spaceOne = spaceOne.Replace("1", "O");
            break;
        case "2":
            spaceTwo = spaceTwo.Replace("2", "O");
            break;
        case "3":
            spaceThree = spaceThree.Replace("3", "O");
            break;
        case "4":
            spaceFour = spaceFour.Replace("4", "O");
            break;
        case "5":
            spaceFive = spaceFive.Replace("5", "O");
            break;
        case "6":
            spaceSix = spaceSix.Replace("6", "O");
            break;
        case "7":
            spaceSeven = spaceSeven.Replace("7", "O");
            break;
        case "8":
            spaceEight = spaceEight.Replace("8", "O");
            break;
        case "9":
            spaceNine = spaceNine.Replace("9", "O");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Option. Please try again");
            break;
    }
}
```

add a checker for each `switch/case` statement

`if (space{numberOfEnteredValue} == {valueOfThatSpace})`

meaning the `spaceOne`/`spaceTwo` and so forth has not been changed yet to either `X` or `O`, `spaceOne == 1`

Comment: I did private static string spaceOne - spaceNine but my board isn't displaying the string values

Comment: @JaadQadadeh, i forgot to mention to add initial values, i will update my answer.

Comment: @JaadQadadeh, updated it, if it helped, you can mark it as an answer and helpful, thanks

Comment: It did, but can you go into some detail on how I can add a checker? I'm new to c#. Thanks for the help

Comment: it will stop overwriting previous value. ill update the answer again.

Comment: I know i just dont know how to implement it. Hopefully the update help me. Thanks for helping out

Comment: @JaadQadadeh updated my answer and due to a lot of switch cases, an example is added in `GetPlayerOneMove` updated it by adding `while` and an `if/else` statement for `spaceOne` continue that to all and also in `GetPlayerTwoMove`

Answer (score 0):

playerOneMove has a local scope, which means it only exists inside the method where you declared it. You should return the value from it and assign that to a variable in your calling loop.

You also need to pass it as a parameter to the next method. You are passing the string "playerOneMove". You don't need to pass a parameter to the method that takes in the first move.

For example:

```
while(gameDone == false)
{
    DrawBoard ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    var playerOneMove = GetSpaceOne();
    PlacePieceOne ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", playerOneMove);

...


private static string GetSpaceOne ()
{
    string playerOneMove;
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.Write("Player One (1-9): ");
    playerOneMove = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
    return playerOneMove;
}
```

Comment: That worked, but it's not replacing in the actual board. what do I have to change in the DrawBoard method to fix it? Thanks